# Documentum Query -DQL

Tags: dql, documentum

How can I form a DQL query to get the list of files excluding the virtual documents created (while adding reference to the file) in document um. Can any one please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `r_link_count` is > zero and object is a document and is virtual-document flag is `true` then you have a virtual document

RTFM Object Reference and DQL Reference for more, in the mean time

- [DQL assistance to get documents from the repository](https://community.emc.com/thread/113940?tstart=0)
- [Useful DQL Queries](http://dionrobin.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/useful-dql-queries/)